# How do I show the lists control by subtracting the group of list control? - livecode

Tags: livecode

How do I show the lists control by subtracting the group of list control?

Here my code:

```
on refreshlistoj idCardCur
   set the dgData of grp "dgG" of card "Main" of stack stackmain to get_elementtodg(idCardCur)
end refreshlistoj

function get_elementtodg namecurrent
   if namecurrent is not empty then
      set the dgData of group "dgG" of stack stackmain to empty
      put the number of controls of card ID namecurrent of stack stackname into numCon
      repeat with crd = 1 to numCon
         put the name of control crd of card ID namecurrent of stack stackname into theDataA[crd]["Col 1"]
         put the short name of control crd of card ID namecurrent of stack stackname into theDataA[crd]["Col 2"]
      end repeat
      return theDataA
   end if
end get_elementtodg
```

My code has show lists all controls.

Answer (score 0):

The `childControlNames` returns all controls of a group. The `childControlIDs` returns a list of ID numbers of all controls of a group. If you want to get a list of any group, card or stack, you can use the following handler:

```
getProp allControls
  if word 1 of the name of the target is among the items of "group,card,stack" then
    put the long id of the target into myTarget
    repeat with x = 1 to the number of controls of myTarget
      put the long id of control x of myTarget & cr after myList
    end repeat
  end if
  return char 1 to -2 of myList
end allControls
```

Put this into the script of your mainstack, a stack in use or a backscript and call it as

```
get the allControls of stack "Your Stack"
put the allCOntrols of cd 1 into fld 1
-- etc
```

It appears that you want to use this for a datagrid. If you can explain why you want this exactly, I might improve my answer.

Comment: The reason why I want this because I want to make it like the Project Browser in Livecode.

Comment: If you just need a complete list of controls and it isn't just about datagrids then I presume my example is sufficient. You can figure our how to display the data in a datagrid yourself.

Comment: Thank you.
I have question for ask you.Now,I make scrolling group with ease in and ease out effect like feel when you swipes on IOS.But I can't it.Can you show example for me?